# weird erlang behavior, dealing with large bitstrings

Tags: erlang

when converting large base64 image (~45k), to bitstring, it raises an exception:

```
exception error: no function clause matching 
                base64:decode("j9/",
                              [255,128,0,65,41,25,37,24,0,4,4,0,0,4,0,4,0,
                               3,255,108,1,12,0,32,24,24,28|...]) (base64.erl, line 254)
 in function  base64:decode/1 (base64.erl, line 118)
```

I really want to understand why it behaves like that (maybe bitstring max size?)

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you sure Image does not have any value before you execute Image = base64:decode(EncodedImage).    ?

Comment: Please if you want to ask another question, do not edit (and wipe) previous one but just create new question.

Comment: In this case the cause of exception is:  there is no function decode with 2 parameters in the module base64

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your base64 data is truncated.  Base64 works by taking groups of 4 characters and converting them to groups of 3 bytes.  If the bitstring is not a multiple of 3 bytes, the base64 text should be padded with one or two `=` signs, so that it's still made up of groups of 4 characters, but your base64 text ends with a group of only 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if the image is properly encoded with base64 by trying to decode it outside Erlang?

See this post how to do that from the command line:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/178521/how-can-i-decode-a-base64-string-from-the-command-line